# C# -Version Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

From Linq to Sql  i received the code (VB version)

```
Dim db as New DBDSDataContext

Dim products
            =_ 
               <Products>
                   <%=From product in db.Products_
                   Select_
                <Product>
                     <ProductName>
                          <%=product.ProductName %>
                     </ProductName>
                          <QuantityPerUnit>
                             <%=product.QuantityPerUnit%>
                           </QuantityPerUnit>
                      </Product>
                   </Products>
```

1) I do not know VB.Please help me to know the equal C# code of the above.

2) Any Utility is available to know VB to C# ?

Comment: just wanna say i've been programming in VB for ~4 months, and have yet to run across "XML literals" in code.  Threw me back for a minute.  Neato

Answer (score 1):

```
DBSDataContext db = new DBSDataContext();
var products = from p in db.Products
select p;
```

I am not sure if that is the select statement that you want... That will return an IEnumerable of Products.

```
foreach(Product prod in products){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I don't have a VS on hand, but it should looks like this in C#. (not test and not verified)

```
var products =new XElement("Products",
                   from product in db.Products
                   select new XElement("Product",
                     new XElement("ProductName",
                          product.ProductName),
                     new XElement("QuantityPerUnit",
                          product.QuantityPerUnit)
                     )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have XML literals, so there is no equivalent (except for building the XML using the the classes in the System.Xml namespace)